# How to set the ArrayList data in to the ListView?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have Data in ArrayList like:

```
[android_metadata, test1, test5, test4, test2, test3, test10, test1002, abcd, zxy, re, test1001, testing, test21, test12]
```

Now i want to Set such data in to the ListView in android.
Please help me in this matter.
I have seen many Example. but should i have to implement getter setter class to store data and display it into ListView ?
I have just to show Just above List of data in to List View and set its ClickEvent.
Please Give me Some code to done such implement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Start extends Activity {

private String[] lv_arr = {};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    // Get a handle to the list view
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

    // Convert ArrayList to array
    lv_arr = (String[]) arrayList.toArray();
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Start.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr));

}


}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the example

```
ArrayList yourlist = new ArrayList();

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yourlist);
yourlistview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Balaji.K's answer, you don't need the `String[]` array.
You can attach an ArrayList to a ListView by using an ArrayAdapter directly:

```
private ArrayList<String> arrayList = Arrays.asList("android_metadata", "test1", "test5", "test4", /*...*/ "test21", "test12");

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList));
```